# Multiple http pages on electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I am using electron to convert my web app to desktop. I have two HTML pages that I would like the user to be able to access. Is there an elegant way to switch between pages via electron? Im thinking like a side panel or something similar. I have tried electron tabs and it was no good.

Comment: What do you mean an elegant way? What way do you currently have it on your web app? There shouldn't need to be any difference when moving it into electron. You can still do the same things design-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Electron only provides a headless chrome environment to run your app in. There should be no difference between your web app and your electron app functionality wise.